# Using Multiple IIF statements in a SQL expression in SQL report builder

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder

I'm adding a new column to an existing report called Refund Due. In this column I'm writing an expression for the following logic:

1. If `incurred > 0` then populate refund due column with `No`
2. If `incurred =< 0 and status = "closed"` then populate refund column with `Yes`
3. If `incurred =< 0 and status does not equal "closed"` then populate refund column with `"Refer"`

I wrote the following expression

```
=IIF (Fields!GROSS_CLAIMS_INCURRED.Value>"0", "No", IIF(Fields!GROSS_CLAIMS_INCURRED.Value<="0" AND Fields!STATUS.Value="Closed", "Yes", IIF(Fields!GROSS_CLAIMS_INCURRED.Value<="0" AND Fields!STATUS.Value="Open", "Refer", IIF(Fields!GROSS_CLAIMS_INCURRED.Value<="0" AND Fields!STATUS.Value="Reopen", "Refer"))
```

But get the following error message when I preview the report:

> The Value expression for the textrun
>   ‘Textbox154.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30516]
>   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'IIf' accepts this
>   number of arguments.

How can i fix this problem or which expression must i use to get required results?

Thanks in Advance for help.

Comment: You have 4 `IIF` statements but only 2 closing brackets at the end - have a look at that and see if that rectifies the issue.

Comment: Your last IIF only has two parameters. It needs three. By the way, this is a job for `CASE ... WHEN ... THEN ... WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END` MUCH easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

`SWITCH` is a much cleaner way of multiple conditional expressions than nested `IIF` statements:

```
=SWITCH(Fields!GROSS_CLAIMS_INCURRED.Value>"0", "No",
Fields!GROSS_CLAIMS_INCURRED.Value<="0" AND Fields!STATUS.Value="Closed", "Yes",
Fields!GROSS_CLAIMS_INCURRED.Value<="0" AND Fields!STATUS.Value="Open", "Refer",
Fields!GROSS_CLAIMS_INCURRED.Value<="0" AND Fields!STATUS.Value="Reopen", "Refer"
)
```